# NoReverseMatch at /upload/ when redirecting

Tags: python, django

When I am executing the code,I get the following error

`NoReverseMatch at /upload/
Reverse for 'compare' with keyword arguments '{u'uploaded_file_url2': '/media/SAMPLE1.xlsx', u'uploaded_file_url': '/media/SAMPLE.xlsx'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['compare/']`

**myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^upload/', views.upload,name='upload'),
        url(r'^compare/(?P<uploaded_file_url>\w+)/(?P<uploaded_file_url2>\w+)$',views.compare,name='compare'),
                 ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myfile=request.FILES['myfile']
        myfile2=request.FILES["myfile2"]
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        filename2=fs.save(myfile2.name, myfile2)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        uploaded_file_url2 = fs.url(filename2)
        return redirect(reverse('myapp:compare',kwargs={"uploaded_file_url":uploaded_file_url,"uploaded_file_url2":uploaded_file_url2 }  ))

    return render(request, 'myapp/upload.html')

def compare(request,uploaded_file_url,uploaded_file_url2):

    a=uploaded_file_url
    b=uploaded_file_url2
    #some code here

    return render(request,'myapp/compare.html',{"a":a,"b":b})
```

Here I want to pass uploaded_file_url and uploaded_file_url2 to compare

Comment: Why your `compare` url name is `home` ?. Change that name to `compare` for correctly redirecting to `compare` url

Comment: No that was by mistake.Still I get the same error

Comment: But still you have to make the url accept keyword argument.  `url(r'^compare/(?P<uploaded_file_url>\w+)/(?P<uploaded_file_url2>\w+)$',...),`

Comment: It still shows the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual url in your codebase now?

Comment: This is my main url   --->        urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('myapp.urls',namespace='myapp')),
]

Comment: okay what about the myapp urls.py ?

Comment: I have updated my code.Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass all the data from the upload to the reverse function, so that it is part of the URL. But your "compare" URL does not expect any arguments at all.

Either change the URL so that it does expect arguments, or pass the uploaded filenames in the GET parameters or in the session.

Comment: If I'm not using reverse what should I do to get the both uploaded_file_urls

Comment: I don't understand your question. You should be using reverse.